# Does an object moving at a constant speed do any work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, free-body-diagram

So lets say there's an object in space, no gravity, and its pushed by a force that acts only for a moment, the object gets to a certain speed and continues moving at a constant velocity. No more forces. Does the object do any work?

Comment: Even if it was being accelerated, the object would do no work. the force however, would be doing work on that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the object is not doing any work. The mathematical relation for work is Work = Force x Displacement. Since no (further) forces are being applied (either upon the object nor by the object), W = 0. Mere motion is not work.

You can think of it in another way: velocity is meters over seconds (or distance over time). Work is measured in Joules (units of energy, or kilograms x meters² over seconds²). So, even looking at the units involved, it doesn't make sense to say mere motion is itself work.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that applied the force to the object does work on the object for the moment it is applied, and that work will equal the increase in kinetic energy of the object. Once the force is removed and the object allowed to continue at constant speed, no net work is done on or by the object, since its kinetic energy remains constant.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly, Thermodynamically speaking momentum $\mathbf p$ is an extensive and velocity $\mathbf v$ is its corresponding intensive variable or its energetic  potential. Momentum "does" work when the velocity changes. The same with entropy and any other conserved quantity be it electric charge or gravitational mass, if it is moved without potential change then no work is done.